# Why should i choose a webservice versus adding the logic to mobile code? Salesforce web versus iOS Native App

Tags: ios, salesforce, mobile-application, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

I work with a team which has a Mobile app integrated with Salesforce acting as a backend.
I am on the mobile team.

I keep getting into arguments with the Salesforce team as to why a certain logic should be written on SF versus mobile.

My usual argument are that mobile application build is supposed to be light, that the heavy logic processing should be on the backend side, that we need to keep code more scalable and controlled from backend so that we dont end up making multiple mobile app releases. The last part goes in line with users having to update the app every time mobile code changes versus a no-action-from-end-user (with may be a little downtime during non-busy hours) if its a backend update.

An example from today:
We have something called as Shipping methods for a functionality in our app. There are two data sources for this. One is for when the user chooses condition A, which is a little complex and needs a REST webservice for mobile to retrieve the Shipping methods. The other is when the user chooses condition B, and is vanilla, straight forward, and the shipping methods can be accessed from mobile using an SOQL query.
Howvere, the output in both the cases is **same, exact kind of data**.

What I suggested was that SF handles both conditions on their side as part of one webservice using an argument provided by mobile.
Agreed the condition B, uses only an SOQL query, performance wise - wont make a lot of difference. Its the same if done from Mobile / Salesforce within a webservice. However I feel it will make the code cleaner and contained, will reduce the lines of code overall.

The SF folks are asking mobile to call the webservice if its condition A, and make the SOQL when it is condition B.
The data from both will have to be parsed separately on mobile, which means that much more code on mobile to handle and process the exact kind of data - twice.
Their argument for this is that they have to write more test classes to handle this. Is that even right to consider test clasess when making such decisions? I do not get it.

Looking for some help and guidance for the best practices. Some documentation which will help make these decisions easier.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably entire books on this topic -- there are many arguments to be made here, and it all depends on specific circumstances regarding performance, security, delivery models, etc.  To me, the two most compelling arguments for server-side logic are:

- It is, generally speaking, easier to deploy fixes/updates to server code than to client code, especially if you have to take App Store approval cycles into consideration.
- It is also easier to control the security environment on the server.  If you are making decisions that could be hacked/spoofed/replayed on the client, you will have to validate them server-side anyway in order to ensure that they are valid for the current user/context, so why not put them there in the first place?

Comment: You said books :) Can you suggest some please?